# Find lower-bound for demand-paging

Tags: virtual-memory, lower-bound, page-fault, demand-paging

I have a system that uses demand-paging 8192 bytes with 2 GiB of RAM. If a running program accesses a total of 280,000 distinct pages of virtual memory over its' lifetime. Is there a way to find the lower-bound with this info only and if it is, then how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lower bound of what?

Comment: I am loathe to close but there has been no clarification.